# Can't change dates in tt_news archive when not logged in

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

A college of mine has set up a page with tt_news single, list and archive.

He has an archive list in a sidebar on all these pages and it lists the years from each news as it should.
I can click on each year and view the news from that year fine when logged in.
But when I log out the date is not changed. It stays at what date was first clicked when the "SHOW ARCHIVED" setting was set.
The url changes but the page doesn't...

I have:
tt_news v2.5.2
Typo3 v4.5.4
CoolURI v1.0.26

CoolUri conf: http://pastebin.com/9xTmVyPn

tt_news typoscript:

```
plugin.tt_news { 
    templateFile = fileadmin/templates/ext/blog.html
    displayArchivedInLatest = 1
    datetimeMinutesToArchive = 1
    enableArchiveDate = 0

    # page with archive list
    archiveTypoLink.parameter = 286
    # page with single view
    singlePid = 285
    # page with list view
    backPid = 284
    # page with db entries 
    pid_list = 35

    displaySingle.date_stdWrap.strftime = %e:e %B %Y
    displayList.date_stdWrap.strftime = %e:e %B %Y

    pageBrowser {
        tableParams >
    }

    summary {
        wordWrap = 105 | ... | 1
    }

    imgMaxWidth = 600
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have an caching issue? Just test it via www.example.com/your/url/?no_cache=1 If that works if you are not logged in, you have an caching issue.

Comment: Yes the problem seems to be the cache. no_cache=1 worked.  But how can I fix this in tt_news? The Url looks like this: ?tx_ttnews[pS]=1293836400&tx_ttnews[pL]=31535999&tx_ttnews[arc]=1

Comment: I would expect that it is a cooluri issue, not an tt_news issue. Well, perhaps biesior is right and someone has altered the default config? Just try to deactivate cooluri.
If not, paste the tt_news configuration.

Comment: Disabling cooluri fixed it so it seems to be the cHash. Here is the cooluri conf: http://pastebin.com/9xTmVyPn